# Retaining the last four fwrite()s in a file using C

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I need some help in maintaining a data log (any .txt file) where I need the last four/five transactions, and erase anything beyond that.

For eg: I created the file.txt using fopen() and started writing using fwrite() from a buffer every 30 secs. The first four writes are OK, but as soon as I write into the file for a fifth time, I want the first entry to be removed and the fifth write() to move to the fourth place and the rest being shifted accordingly ie second goes to first, third goes to second. NB: Every write() data is of same time and size as if a temperature reading or a humidity reading.

thanks
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

1. Create temporary file.
2. Copy 4 newest entries from older file.
3. Add new entry.
4. Delete old file.
5. Rename temporary file to real file name.

Comment: Ok I got the point, but for recurring incoming data, I have to create a temporary file everytime and copy the data from the previously created file and then delete the same. I am talking about inflow of data every 30 secs. So doing the above procedure every 30 secs seems to be a bit of an overhead.

Comment: Here are a few points if you can help me with: 1. How to count the number of lines written onto a file?? 2.How to delete "n" lines of entry/data from a file? This will help me to get the cursor to the start of the file using F_SEEK and delete "n" lines because everytime the number of lines written is fixed and equal to the previous entry.

Comment: @GauravPratimTalukdar How big is the overhead? Remember that you will get *some* protection against data corruption, as old file won't be overridden, until new file has been written.

Answer (score 0):

Then just use [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) to reach to the last character in the first entry (remember - files are like arrays - first byte is indexed 0 and so on) and then just use [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) or [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) to print `\b` in a loop onto the file as `\b` means backspace and will delete the characters. Do that until the file starts with the second entry OR untill the file cursor is at 0 index (use [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) to see if it is) and then use [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) again to return to the index you were at before (again, you can save that index into a variable using [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) to see what you're current position is) and then write the fifth to the file :P